# Ошибка после перезагрузки компонента Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Я учу VUE.JS и столкнулся с не понятной ошибкой.
Вот в чем суть:

Получаю данные через axios с Гугл Таблицы и передаю их в state vuex

```
actions: {
    LOAD_NEWS ({ commit }) {
          axios
            .get('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/URL/1/public/values?alt=json')
            .then(response => response.data.feed.entry)
            .then(news => {
            commit('SET_NEWS', news)
            })          
        }
},
mutations: {
    SET_NEWS(state, news) {
            state.news = news
        }
}
```

Вызов массива данных в компоненте:

```
    export default {
        name: 'News',
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['news'])
        },
        created() {
            this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_NEWS')
        }
    }
```

А затем в компоненте детального просмотра показываю нужный элемент массива по индексу:

```
<h1 class="news__title"> {{news[20].gsx$title.$t}} </h1>
<p class="news__announce"> {{news[20].gsx$announce.$t}} </p>
```

Код работает, на страницу выводит нужные данные и не показывает никаких ошибок, но если перезагрузить страницу, то в консоли выдаст ошибку

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'gsx$title' of undefined"
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'gsx$title' of undefined
```

При этом компонент попрежнему работает и показывает все данные.

Подскажите, чем может быть вызвана эта ошибка. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Осмелюсь предположить, что на момент рендеринга компонента, `vue` не находит свойства `gsx$title` в объекте `news` (потому что, на момент загрузки компонента скорее всего `news === undefined` или заданное вами по умолчанию, допустим `news = []`, а следовательно `vue` не находит у него свойства `[20]` и тем более `[20].gsx$title`), о чем и предупреждает вас ошибкой:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'gsx$title' of undefined
```

и чтобы избежать этого, вам следует использовать [условную отрисовку](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html), которая позволит вам отобразить ваш блок только в том случае, если выражение директивы возвращает значение, приводимое к `true`.

что-то вроде этого:

```
<div v-if="news && news.length > 0">
  <h1 class="news__title"> {{news[20].gsx$title.$t}} </h1>
  <p class="news__announce"> {{news[20].gsx$announce.$t}} </p>
</div>
```

Вы должны понять суть условной отрисовки, чтобы избежать большинства подобных ошибок в будущем

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, это очень помогло!